# Continue inside nested loop in C

Tags: c, nested-loops, continue

How does continue work for following example?

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if( j && j->data != some_data) {
        continue;
    }

    if(j) {
       /* do something */
    }
}
```

Can  I combine these two inside loop and achieve the same result like:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(j) {
       if(j->data != some_data) {
          continue;
       }

       /* do something */
     }
}
```

Comment: An `if` statement is not a loop.

Comment: Yess, that will work.

Comment: Okay thanks @Quentin.

Comment: Ohh My bad @GovindParmar. So it doesn't matter how many if statements are present inside for loop. Thanks for clarification !

Comment: @Quentin: which way is better? First one or second?

Comment: `if( j &&  (j->data != some_data) )` would do.

Comment: When building the assembly code for the two statements it depend on how the compiler sets it up. Most compilers will set up the logic for the first to be equivalent to the second. Thus, it will not matter.

Comment: @m.raynal: Thank you! Which way is better and why? Can you please tell me?

Comment: some people (including me) consider the `if( j && j->data != some_data) continue;` version more readable. And: this isnot a nested loop, continue and break only refer to loops. (and break also to switches)

Comment: as sabbahillel said, the compiler might optimise these statements for you, therefore, you could privilege the most human-friendly one, helping you having a clear view of what you're checking and being sure you don't make mistakes.

Comment: Thanks again for your help and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example does not contain a nested loop.  There is only one `for` and/or `while` in the code.  Therefore the location of the `continue` statement depends only on your program logic.

If you do have a nested loop, then a `continue` or `break` affects only the innermost loop.

Answer (score 1):

Why use `continue` at all?

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if( j && j->data == some_data) {
       /* do something */
    }
}
```